# Как просмотреть записи в середине таблицы, в которой есть столбец имя категории?

Tags: mysql

Есть структура бд для сайта, где для каждой категории создана отдельная таблица.

Хочу переделать на хранение категории в одной таблице, но в этом случае я не знаю как выводить последние `n` записей и перемещаться в глубь списка.

Попытался сделать так:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  $table
WHERE
  category='$onecategory'
ORDER BY id DESC
LIMIT $count, 5
```

то есть переменная `$count` ( которая должна перемещать указатель в глубь списка) ничего не дает и вывод на экран пустой.

Как правильно перемещаться по записям сверху вниз по столбику с именем категории?

Уточнение:

В однородной таблице(то есть где все записи одинаковой категории) по `id` перемещатся легко... `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT $count, 5` а вот если таблица неоднородна, тоесть столбик с именем категории может содержать различные значения, как перемещаться вглубь списка в этом случае? если припадет `$count` на строку с `id`, в которой не окажется соответствующее имя категории. так как оно че то выводит тогда пустое место на страницу

Comment: $count посмотрите

Comment: выведите ваш `$comand` на экран и выполните этот запрос в консоли mysql. Скорее всего сразу поймете в чем ошибка (либо покажите итоговый запрос здесь, чтобы мы знали что происходит). У вас может `$table` содержит зарезервированное слово (тогда надо в обратные кавычки его взять), может быть у вас `$onecategory` в базе отсутствует, может быть вы `$count` как-то не так рассчитываете. И было бы не плохо, если бы вы привели пример базы здесь и в http://sqlfiddle.com/ и добавили код формирования параметров запроса.